# First Order Logic Proof

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

I have these $4$ sentences.

**1) Dogs and Cats are pets.**

**2) Pluto and Bruno are dogs.**

**3) Kitty is a cat.**

**4) All dogs except Bruno eat bones.**

I turned them in First-Order Logic Form.

1. $∀x(\mathrm{dog}(x) \to p(x) \wedge  \mathrm{cat}(x) \to p(x))$
2. $\mathrm{dog(Pluto)} \wedge \mathrm{dog(Bruno)}$
3. $\mathrm{Cat(Kitty)}$
4. $∀x(((\mathrm{dog}(x)\wedge \neg \mathrm{ dog(Bruno))} \to \mathrm{E}(x,\mathrm{bones))} \wedge \mathrm{ ((dog}(x) \wedge \mathrm{dog(Bruno))} \to \neg \mathrm{E}(x,\mathrm{bones)))}$

I am not sure if sentence 4 is correct.

I need to prove the following sentence is correct:

**Pluto doesn't eat bones.**

I need to also prove the following sentence is not correct:

**Pluto eats bones.**

I tried negating both statements to prove them but I must have done something wrong. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your 4 is not correct. Note that your:

$$\forall x ((Dog(x) \land \neg Dog(Bruno)) \to E(x,bones))$$

is trivially true given that $Dog(Bruno)$ is True, and hence $\neg Dog(Bruno)$ is False, and hence $Dog(x) \land \neg Dog(Bruno)$ is false for any $x$, and hence $(Dog(x) \land \neg Dog(Bruno)) \to E(x,bones)$ is True for any $x$, regardless of whether or not $x$ eats bones or not.  So this is not what you want.

Instead, for the first half, try this:

$$\forall x ((Dog(x) \land \neg x = Bruno) \to E(x,bones))$$

Can you do the other half now yourself?

By the way: I don't see how you would prove that Pluto does not eat bones, given that Pluto is a dog and all dogs except Bruno do eat bones....

Comment: This was a problem in the exam finals of a course at my university. They first wanted the students to turn those sentences into a consistent set on First Logic Form and they said they need to represent knowledge that isn't mentioned in the text. I haven't given this course yet, it was from an older exam I try to understand how to solve it.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what is meant by 'represent knowledge that isn't mentioned in the text' ... do you?

Comment: By the way: to represent that Bruno does not eat bones you can just do $\neg E(Bruno, bones)$ as a separate statement.  But if you want it inside a universal, you can do:  $$\forall x (Dog(x) \to ( \neg x = Bruno) \leftrightarrow E(x,bones)))$$

Comment: can it be done without =

Comment: @Alex No, sentences like these is exactly the reason why logic has a special = symbol as part of its fixed language.